# Count of date period

Tags: javascript, typescript, date

I have a list of dates like this:

`[ "2020-08-20", "2020-08-20", "2020-08-21", "2020-08-24", "2020-08-25", "2020-08-25", "2020-08-25", ]`

and I need to extract ranges from this list where dates are the same in ascending order for dates.

so for example, my output must be:

```
{date: "2020-08-20", period: 1-2}, {date: "2020-08-21", period: 3-3}, {date: "2020-08-25", period: 4-4},
{date: "2020-08-25", period: 5-7}
```

or simply only:

```
{date: "2020-08-20", period: 1-2},{date: "2020-08-25", period: 5-7}
```

can anyone help me? i try to use an library momentjs to this but it not work :(

thanks for any help

Comment: How were you trying to use moment.js?  What _exactly_ are you trying to do here?  Can you explain where the `period` is coming from?

Comment: your expected output is not valid unless you expect to perform a mathematical operation to arrive at each value of `period`

Comment: your expected outcome is not valid, the period value should be string, check the answer i posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for 2 pointer solution considering your example of sorted date:

For scenario 1:

```js
var data = ["2020-08-20", "2020-08-20", "2020-08-21", "2020-08-24", "2020-08-25", "2020-08-25", "2020-08-25"];

let i = 0, j = 1;
var res = [];
while (i < data.length) {
    if (data[i] == data[j]) {
        j += 1;
        //scan rest
        while (data[i] == data[j]) {
            j += 1;
        }
        j -= 1;
        res.push({ date: data[i], period: (i + 1) + "-" + (j + 1) });
        i = j + 1;
        j = i + 1;
    } else {
        res.push({ date: data[i], period: (i + 1) + "-" + (i + 1) });
        i += 1;
        j += 1;
    }

}
console.log(res);
```

For scenario 2:

```js
var data = ["2020-08-20", "2020-08-20", "2020-08-21", "2020-08-24", "2020-08-25", "2020-08-25", "2020-08-25"];

let i = 0, j = 1;
var res = [];
while (i < data.length) {
    if (data[i] == data[j]) {
        j += 1;
        while (data[i] == data[j]) {
            j += 1;
        }
        j -= 1;
        res.push({ date: data[i], period: (i + 1) + "-" + (j + 1) });
        i = j + 1;
        j = i + 1;
    } else {
        i += 1;
        j += 1;
    }

}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hey, I do not know but with this list `[ 2020-09-24T22:00:00.000Z,
  2020-09-24T22:00:00.000Z,
  2020-09-28T22:00:00.000Z,
  2020-09-30T22:00:00.000Z,
  2020-10-03T22:00:00.000Z,
  2020-10-28T23:00:00.000Z,
  2020-11-19T23:00:00.000Z ]` not work for me :/

Comment: in second solution

Comment: @MotoMoto, your array is not valid, what have you tried so far, I pointed out the way, you need to try for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly simple version that finds the list of unique values and then finds their period using the first and last indices of each value in the original array.

This is only valid if the items start out sorted.  If you could have multiple periods for the same date, because another value intervened, it would require different code (and perhaps updated specs.)

```js
const extract = (dates) =>
  [...new Set(dates)] // get array of unique values
    .map(date => ({   // convert each to a {date, period} object
      date, 
      period: `${dates .indexOf (date) + 1}-${dates .lastIndexOf (date) + 1}`
    }))
      
const input = [ "2020-08-20", "2020-08-20", "2020-08-21", "2020-08-24", "2020-08-25", "2020-08-25", "2020-08-25"]
  

console .log (extract (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```